# Django: Saving instance only if it does not exist already

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I only want to save an instance of Location if the address does not exist already.

Currently when you try to save with an address that already exists you receive a BAD REQUEST.

How can I override the save function to achieve this? And would this be the right way to do it?

current model:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, null=True)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    field_quality = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=3, decimal_places=1, null=True,)
    field_availability = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=3, decimal_places=1, null=True,)
    place_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.objects.filter(address=[self.address]).exists():
            pass
        else:
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already using `unique=True` in the model. It will ensure that you do not have duplicate addressed in that table. Now, regarding bad request, I think that is a proper implementation, duplicate addresses should get 400 bad request. Now, if you still want to give 200 for duplicate addresses then it is better to handle the `IntegrityError` error in the view by catching the exception using try catch. Like this:

```
from django.db import IntegrityError

try:
     Location.objects.create(...)
except IntegrityError:
    # handle error
```