# objects.get(id = id) only works randomly

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I think somewhat related: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61671540/django-saving-instance-only-if-it-does-not-exist-already). I create a model entry:

```
def bulk_asset_update(stores, links, img):
    def do_update(id):
        task = ThreadTask.objects.get(pk = id) ## <--- DOES NOT EXIST SOMETIMES

        ...
        task.is_done = True
        task.timestamp_end = timezone.now()
        task.save()

    task = ThreadTask()
    task.name = "update"
    task.save()

    t = threading.Thread(target = do_update, args = [task.id])
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()   
    return {"id": task.id}
```

Sometimes (every 5th time or so) the `ThreadTask.get(pk = id)` line fails - so I suspect it might not be written to the database yet maybe? I tried replacing the lines:

```
task = ThreadTask()
task.name = "update"
task.save()
```

with:

```
task = ThreadTask.objects.create(name = "update")
```

which seams to work better. But can I make sure that the `task` object is really saved first before code execution continues?

**edit**

I just stumbled across a related issue with a related code of mine, that is tested and reproducible on SQLite and MariaDB:

```
def update_product_in_db(product):
    def do_update(product, task):
        ## get all link objects for this product:
        for link in Link.objects.filter(products = product):
            product_pks = [p.pk for p in link.products.all()]
            product_qs = Product.objects.filter(pk__in = product_pks)
            for product in product_qs:
                print("TEST", product.data)
            img = generate_img(product_qs) 
            task.timestamp_end = timezone.now()
        task.is_done = True
        task.save()

    ## check if a task for logging was already handed to the function
    task = BigTask.objects.create(name = "update products in db")
    t = threading.Thread(target = do_update, args = [product, task])
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()   
    return {'id': task.id}
```

and this function is called from another that semantically does something like:

```
def batch_update_products_in_db(csv_file, store, delimiter = ";"):
    with open(csv_file, encoding = "utf-8") as inputfile:
        reader = csv.reader(inputfile, delimiter = delimiter)
        for row in reader:
            productdata = {header[i]: row[i] for i in range(1, len(row))}                
            product = Product.objects.get(store = store, number = row[0])
            product.data = productdata
            product.save(update_fields = ["data",])
            update_product_in_db(product)
        
    return True
```

When uploading a file that changes the `price` from `12` to `13` This results in an output:

```
TEST: {"name": "hello", "price": "12"} <----
TEST: {"name": "hello", "price": "13"}
TEST: {"name": "hello", "price": "13"}
TEST: {"name": "hello", "price": "13"}
```

Comment: Wow, it's really odd. Django uses thread-local connections and autocommit mode, plus wraps all ORM operations with transaction. I don't see how `model.save()` could be not thread-safe (committed not immediately). What is your DB backend? I cannot reproduce this on `sqlite` (loop of 1000 iterations), haven't checked `postgres` yet. It this example really MRE? Don't you have `transaction.atomic` somewhere (maybe in surrounding code)? Isn't there explicit `db.connection(s)` usage somewhere near?

Comment: I rarely see the error, but it is reproducible. I tested it on SQLite. No atomic whatever or an explicit `db.connections(s)` limit.

Comment: @xtlc Per default Django should commit the transaction when the response from the view happens correctly. Probably this sometimes happens the code in the thread runs. Maybe try to wrap the `task.save()` in its own transaction with something like `with transaction.atomic()`...

Comment: I added another example where I can see this behavior and test it.